# При длительном парсинге сайт перестал выдавать данные

Tags: парсер

Постоянно парсил кинопоиск топ 250 фильмов, как в один момент при выполнении (request).text не выдает всю страницу, а лишь малая часть и в непонятных символах(

ÐžÐ¹ - символы по типу таких

Answer (score 2):

Ну естественно Кинопоиск не хочет давать себя парсить, потому и блокирует ваш айпи. Вот и вся мистика.